# pytest.config.getoption alternative is failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

My setup is such that; `pytest test.py` executes nothing while `pytest --first-test test.py` executes the target function `test_skip`.

In order to determine whether a certain test should be conducted or not, this is what I have been using:

```
skip_first = pytest.mark.skipif(
        not (
                pytest.config.getoption("--first-test")
                or os.environ.get('FULL_AUTH_TEST')
                ), reason="Skipping live"
)

@skip_first
def test_skip():
    assert_something
```

Now that, `pytest.config.getoption` is being deprecated, I am trying to update my code. This is what I have written:

```
@pytest.fixture
def skip_first(request):
    def _skip_first():
        return pytest.mark.skipif(
            not (
                request.config.getoption("--first-test")
                or os.environ.get('FULL_AUTH_TEST')),
            reason="Skipping"
            )
    return _skip_first()

# And, to call:

def test_skip(skip_first):
   assert 1==2
```

However, whether I do `pytest test.py` or `pytest --first-test test.py`, `test_skip` will always execute. But, the skip_first seems to be working fine - Inserting a print statement shows `skip_first = MarkDecorator(mark=Mark(name='skipif', args=(False,), kwargs={'reason': 'Skipping first'}))`, when `--first-test` is given, and args=(True) when given. (Same thing was observed when using the first setup).

Am I missing something?? I even tried to return the function `_skip_first` instead of it's output in the `def skip_first` but no difference.

When using a test class, the manual indicates we need to use `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("fixturename")` but that proved to be of no use either (with classes).

Ideas? This is my system: `platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

In order to cause a `SKIP` from a fixture, you must raise `pytest.skip`.  Here's an example using your code above:

```
import os

import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def skip_first(request):
    if (
            request.config.getoption("--first-test")
            or os.environ.get('FULL_AUTH_TEST')
    ):
        raise pytest.skip('Skipping!')

# And, to call:

def test_skip(skip_first):
   assert 1==2
```

If you want, you can almost replace your original code by doing:

```
@pytest.fixture
def skip_first_fixture(request): ...

skip_first = pytest.mark.usefixtures('skip_first_fixture')

@skip_first
def test_skip(): ...
```

Here's the execution showing this working:

```
$ pytest t.py -q
F                                                                        [100%]
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_skip ___________________________________

skip_first = None

    def test_skip(skip_first):
>      assert 1==2
E      assert 1 == 2
E        -1
E        +2

t.py:16: AssertionError
1 failed in 0.03 seconds


$ pytest t.py --first-test -q
s                                                                        [100%]
1 skipped in 0.01 seconds
```